What buffs/effects connect two beings?
I'm looking for a comprehensive list of buffs and effects that can connect my PC (Arcanist level 14, Mythic 3) and my Cohort (Witch level 12, soon to be unspecified Mythic).
What I need is something mechanical that will translate fluff connection between those 2 characters. Short version is: witch is of magic-eating race and she was initially saved from captivity, feeding on my arcanist since then. On top of that witch is of race that couldn't become a god, while my arcanist could. They are going through a ritual that will "average out" their existences allowing witch to become a god too while also making them permanently connected. That very connection is something I want to translate into game mechanics.
Preferable options: both positive and negative, we're OP already, don't need more OP.
I've considered Battlemind Link but I'm using that already anyway so that's not much of a change, I've considered Protector Familiar abilities but this seems broken, I've considered lich-style being each other's Phylactery but that's 140k GP value each and that's all I got.
DISCLAIMER: RAW game.

Teamwork feats are the general case of "I would like these characters to do something fancy together." For this specific case, I'd look at Share Spells and Special Delivery, both of which require Bonded Mind as a prerequisite. These give your partner the ability to handle your spells the same as your own familiar. I.e., you can cast spells that are normally locked to self-only on your partner, and they can hold the charge and make attacks with touch spells that you cast.
Note that unlike most teamwork feats, they only need the recipient to have Bonded Mind and not the further feats, but two-way magic transfer will need both character to have the later feat as well. Also, they do technically require the character casting the altered spells to have a familiar or equivalent, but that's not difficult to achieve and/or handwave. Consider the Mascot familiar archetype to continue keeping the two characters interchangeable.

Sadly, teamwork feats are literally useless, getting the worse the higher level PC's are and are not amazing even on level 1. I'm looking for something in-line with current power level. Something positive good enough to actually come into play and something negative to actually be a pain in return.
